# Adding rss feed to codeigniter application

Tags: codeigniter, rss

I want to add rss feed to my codeigniter application.
Is there any step by step tutorial to add rss feed in codeigniter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feed Google with codeigniter and css you find this: [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-an-rss-2-0-feed-with-codeigniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-an-rss-2-0-feed-with-codeigniter/)